# How to train a Deep Neural Network to predict conditional probability distribution?

Tags: time-series, conditional-probability, conv-neural-network, timeseries-segmentation

I am working with non-stationary time series data sampled at 128 Hz. I have segmented the entire time series into 1-second segments, meaning now I have a bunch of vectors, say $x_i$, where i = 1,2,3,..500 (500-sec data). Each vector will contain 128 data points, and I have corresponding labels (there are five labels/classes) for each vector. I have trained a neural network to classify these 1-second signals.

I want to find the probability of occurrence of Class-5 in 2nd-second ($x_2$) given I had the vector $x_1$ (1st second) and its label Class-1. i.e., I want to find the probability of occurrence of Class-5 after classifying every second until the end. How can I train a deep neural network to get this task done? Please give me your valuable suggestions.

I was working with EEG data where I wanted to predict the onset of seizures in advance. I have to identify class-5 as early as possible for seizure prediction. That's why I wanted to calculate probability of occurrence of class-5 after each and every second.

Class-4 represents where the seizure is actually happening (in my data), and Class-5 just precedes it. As I wanted to predict seizures before its onset, I wanted to identify Class-5 as early as possible or atleast I want to calculate its probability of occurrence so that I can raise an alarm if the probability is high.

Comment: Could you clarify: Why do you need the first step? Why not predict the next label from the $x_i$ in the previous seconds?

Comment: @frank Predicting next label ($x_2$) given label of $x_1$ is also helpful. Kindly share your thoughts on how to do this.

Comment: @frank I was actually working with EEG data where I wanted to predict the onset of seizures in advance. I have to identify class-5 as early as possible for seizure prediction. That's why I wanted to calculate probability of occurrence of class-5 after each and every second. Hope I have answered your question. Please let me know again in case of any further clarification.

Comment: So you have EEG data for situations where there is no seizure in the near future and then you have EEG data for when there is seizure happening in the near future. Correct? And you want to predict one of five possible "degrees" of seizure? Do you want to predict the time to the next seizure?

Comment: @frank Yes. So Class-4 represents where the seizure is actually happening (in my data), and Class-5 just precedes it. As I wanted to predict seizures before its onset, I wanted to identify Class-5 as early as possible or atleast I want to calculate its probability of occurrence so that I can raise an alarm if the probability is high.

Comment: This seems like predicting the probability of each class rather than making a hard classification. Is that correct?

Comment: @Dave Yes. You are correct. It would be helpful for me if you can share your thoughts on this or refer any topics I need to look on.